# nmcli lists connection profile, but does not show in nmcli con show

Tags: nmcli

When I run `nmcli con show` it returns

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE            DEVICE 
bond0               a8489b17-71bc-441d-981c-f3fe3184fdd7  bond            bond0
```

but when I run `nmcli con show bond0` it returns

```
Error: bond0 - no such connection profile.
```